# https and wildcard subdomain that include index.php in the URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I’m having trouble with https and wildcard subdomain that include index.php in the URLs. My https document root is / and the wildcard document root is /wildcard. Anytime I go to a URL that uses all three like this https://anything.domain.com/index.php displays the /index.php file. The combination of https and index.php is making wildcard subdomain URLs get the root /index.php instead of the wildcard/index.php. Here is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www. domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www. domain.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/?(.*)$ /wildcard/admin/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://([a-z0-9]+\.)? domain.com/$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /wildcard/index.php [L]
```

I have tried adding things like %{HTTPS} on to the last rule above so it will go to the wildcard folder if it includes https but it didn’t work for me. Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Here is a video explaining/showing the problem if you have the time to watch.

http://www.bankits.com/capture-23/capture-23.html

Answer (score 0):

**B****u****t** the urls to images is broken. I thought it would benefit a wider audience to put my answer here instead of in a private reply.

So you have like: `http://www.domain.com/subdomain/` and the subdomain is working as a root when entering with a browser, but urls for images (and other resources later on) is not working, they are basically asking for a full qualified url from the main domain.

You could edit all your content and put full qualified urls there, but there is an easier way.

Use the module pathologic

Pathologic requires Filters to be enabled, and then you set it up for each filter you want it to scan, usualy "full html" and "filtered html". If you set it up for using "Full URL", you will enter all the base paths you need, fx. like this:

Pathologic will look for your resources in all base paths you set up. In you content you will just have to enter the relative path from one of these roots. A relative url for the bartik logo would then be:
`src="themes/bartik/logo.png"`. Do NOT start your relative url with `"/"!`
Make sure that "Correct URLs with Pathologic" is the LAST filter in the Filter processing order, and from there on it's fire and forget, you don't have to think about that problem anymore.

Comment: If you can watch this it will explain it better to you 

bankits.com/capture-23/capture-23.html